# Versioning of Web API in .Net Core 1.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2

I would like to use the following library in order to implement versioning for my Web API application (using .NET Core 1.0). However as this library is currently pre-release I haven't been able to find any documentation for it.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning/1.0.0-beta1

Are there any examples on how to use this library? Or source code? Does it support specifying the version in the URL query string? E.g. http://www.example.com/api/products?version=1

I've also considered the following library however it doesn't appear to support .NET Core:

https://github.com/Sebazzz/SDammann.WebApi.Versioning

Answer (score 5):

To answer my own questions:

Source code (including samples) is available here:

https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning

There are also some pointers to documentation at the bottom of this link.

It supports the versioning semantics outlined by [the Microsoft REST Guidelines](https://github.com/Microsoft/api-guidelines/blob/master/Guidelines.md#12-versioning), so it supports specifying the version in the query string.